# How to map enums to integers implicitliy

Tags: java, android

I know I'm not using the right jargon, but basically I want to take this code in C++ and port it over to Java

```
public enum Packets {

    // Maps enums to integers 0-3
    PACKET_NONE = 0, PACKET_SYNC, 
    PACKET_EXPECT_TO_RECEIVE, PACKET_AVAIL_1, 

    // Maps enums to integers 13-16
    PACKET_FILL = 13,  PACKET_GLASS, PACKET_FILLi, PACKET_GLASSi
}
```

I want to explicitly map an enum to an int, and then have every subsequent enum implicitly map to the next increment of that integer (or some solution as close to this C code as possible).

Comment: Java enums are essentially implicitly defined to their ordinals (enum index). Each enum constant is a new object itself, so if you were to assign it as a `String` then it'd be nothing other than a `public static final String`. Which you can define as many of as you want with or without it being an enum. However if that were a java enum, then `Packets.PACKET_NONE.ordinal()` would return 0, and `Packets.PACKET_SYNC.ordinal()` would return 1, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this, of course?

Comment: I just need a way to map enums to integers as quickly as possible, and this code does just that, but I see no equivalent in Java

Comment: Are the integers non-continuous?

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks for articulating that

Comment: Others have shown adding methods/getters/properties to enums, outside of that you can use java 8's stream api to achieve a `Map<Packets, Integer>` for their ids (something analogous to `Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Packets::getId)`, using `#collect` on a stream of `Packets` objects).

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can assign values to Enum if that's what you are looking for. It will look like this:

```
public enum Packets {
    PACKET_NONE(0),
    PACKET_SYNC(1),
    PACKET_EXPECT_TO_RECEIVE(2),
    PACKET_AVAIL_1(3);

    private int value;

    Packets(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can call enum like this to get it's value:

```
Packets.PACKET_SYNC.getValue(); //It will return 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a field to your enum, intialize this field in the enumeration constant's constructor call and then return this field from a public getter. This should look about like this:

```
public enum Packets
{
    PACKET_NONE(0),
    PACKET_SYNC(1),
    PACKET_EXPECT_TO_RECEIVE(2),
    PACKET_AVAIL_1(3),
    PACKET_FILL(13),
    PACKET_GLASS(14),
    PACKET_FILLI(15),
    PACKET_GLASSI(16);

    private final int id;

    private MyEnum(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not that clean of a solution but if you really want to auto-initialize them to increment the same way the C++ declaration does, without explicitly defining each individual ID, you can do something like this:

```
public enum Packets
{
    PACKET_NONE(0),
    PACKET_SYNC(1),
    PACKET_EXPECT_TO_RECEIVE(2),
    PACKET_AVAIL_1(3),
    PACKET_FILL(13),
    PACKET_GLASS(),
    PACKET_FILLI(),
    PACKET_GLASSI();

    private int id;

    private Packets(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Packets(){
        this.id = -1;
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void initIds(){
        for(Packets p : Packets.values()){
            if(p.getId()==-1){
                if(p.ordinal()==0){
                    p.setId(0);
                }else{
                    p.setId(Packets.values()[p.ordinal()-1].getId()+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call the initialize and it will fill in the ID's for you:

```
Packets.initIds();
System.out.println(Packets.PACKET_AVAIL_1.getId()); //3
System.out.println(Packets.PACKET_GLASS.getId()); //13
System.out.println(Packets.PACKET_FILL.getId()); //14
System.out.println(Packets.PACKET_FILLI.getId()); //15
```

**edit/addition:**

If you move the code from the `initIds()`method into a static initializer block, you do not need the initialize call somewhere in your code:

```
public enum Packets {
    PACKET_NONE(0),
    PACKET_SYNC(1),
    PACKET_EXPECT_TO_RECEIVE(2),
    PACKET_AVAIL_1(3),
    PACKET_FILL(13),
    PACKET_GLASS(),
    PACKET_FILLI(),
    PACKET_GLASSI();

    static {
        for (Packets p : Packets.values()) {
            if (p.getId() == -1) {
                if (p.ordinal() == 0) {
                    p.setId(0);
                } else {
                    p.setId(Packets.values()[p.ordinal() - 1].getId() + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int id;

    private Packets(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Packets() {
        this.id = -1;
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: upvote for this, because it mimics the desired autoincrement.

Comment: While this meets the autoincrement requirement the code is not nice to look at. Especially the fact that the static block is executed after several constructor calls is non-intutive to say the least. Also if you wonder what id PACKET_GLASSI has the autoincrement forces you to count the constants instead of just reading it behind its definition.